# How to group some columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe
[image]

I need to group columns with numbers into one column.  And make a final dataframe look like this. 
[image]

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Can you please show what you have tried?

Comment: You can do this by first dropping the columns you want to exclude from the computation `df.drop(list_of_cols_to_drop, axis=1)` then perform a row-wise sum `df.sum(axis=1)` and finally add the result to the original dataframe. By combining these three steps you'll have the desired effect:`df['sum'] = df.drop(list_of_cols_to_drop, axis=1).sum(axis=1)`.

Comment: @Djib2011 I don't want them to exclude,  I just want to group it to one column :)

Comment: I mean the other columns (reporting_date, id_region, etc.) that you don't want to sum.

Comment: @Djib2011 How to group them 101, 102... etc to one column? :D

Comment: you want to sum them right? the `df.sum(axis=1)` does exactly that

Comment: @Djib2011 thanks did by my own way, by using df2 = pd.melt(df2, id_vars=["reporting_date",'ДОХОДЫ, всего'], 
                  var_name="id_region", value_name="Sum")